Sufficient property for a reflector to map a morphism to an isomorphism
Hi I need to show the following:
Let $L,R$ be two adjoint functors,
$C
\underset{R}
{
   \stackrel{L}
   {
      \underset{\longleftarrow}
      {\stackrel{\longrightarrow}{\scriptsize\perp}}
   }
}
D
$
. Furthermore suppose $R$ is fully faithful1. Let $x,y \in C$ and assume $f: x\to y$ a morphism:
If $f: Hom(y,Rd) \to Hom(x,Rd)$ is a bijection for every $d\in C$ then $L(f)$ is an isomorphism. I tried some things but I am not able to show this, does anyone have  a good hint for that?
I tried the following things: I want to show that $Lf: Lx \to Ly$ is a isomorphism i.e I want an invers map. So I looked at:
$Hom(Lx,Ly) \to Hom(x,RLy) \to Hom(y,RLy) \to Hom(Ly,Ly) $ where every map is a bijection (1) adjunction, 2) is given by assumption, 3) adjunnction again). Now I thought that I can maybe show that $L(f)$ is mapped to the identity (but Im not sure how as I do not know anything about the adjunction maps, just that they are bijections). Moreover I do not know how to use that $R$ is fully faithfull, as for this I would need something with R in both the Hom arguments.
1In this case one says $L$ is a reflector.

Please show us what you've tried.

Is $L:C\to D: R$ shorthand for $L: C\to D$ and $R:D\to C$?  I've never seen that before. It's kind of clever except the one-way arrow spoils it.

I went ahead and helped with the adjoint latex because I found it was nontrivial...

Thank you for elaborating!

I wrote down what I tried so far. its for me hard to write down, because I have just tried to insert different things for $d$ in the assumption and than reshape that. Im not sure if something of that works. I wrote down the in my opinion most promissing choice I tried. Maybe someone can help me now

I also took the liberty to get you a better post title.  You did a good job adding to the post.  I am looking forward to seeing solutions...

@rschwieb I have seen this notation before in the context of adjunctions.

@MartinBrandenburg It works OK, especially if one can't format fancily.

We have a commutative diagram
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\hom(Ly,d) & \rightarrow & \hom(Lx,d) \\
\downarrow && \downarrow \\
\hom(y,Rd) & \rightarrow & \hom(x,Rd) 
\end{array}$$
The vertical arrows come from the adjunction and are isomorphisms, the horizontal arrows are induced by $x \to y$. By assumption, the bottom arrow is an isomorphism. Hence, the same is true for the top arrow, for every $d$. By the Yoneda-Lemma, this means that $Lx \to Ly$ is an isomorphism.
It is not necessary to assume that $R$ is fully faithful. This holds for every adjunction.

thank you for your answer, how does it follow by Yoneda Lemma that $Lx \to Ly$ is an isomorphism. I saw the Yoenda Lemma es follows: If $F: I \to Set$ is a functor then there is a bijection $Nat(Hom(x,-),F(-)) \to F(x)$. I dont see the connection at the moment.

I mean what I get is that from Yoneda we have $Nat(Hom(Ly,-),Hom(Lx,-)) \to Hom(Lx,Ly) $ is a bijection and we have here a natural transformation described in your diagram, but  I am missing the final argument somehow.

The Yoneda embedding is fully faithful, hence conservative, hence if $\mathrm{Hom}(Lf, -)$ is an isomorphism, so is $Lf$. Explicitly, if $g : \mathrm{Hom}(Ly, -) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(Lx, -)$ then you have $g(\mathrm{id}{Ly}) = Lf : \mathrm{Hom}(Lx, Ly)$ and $g^{-1}(\mathrm{id}{Lx}) : \mathrm{Hom}(Ly, Lx)$, and it's not hard to check that these are inverses. Walking through all these steps is a good exercise.
